# Developing queryset using related models

Tags: django, django-models

I've got two models. Event and Usercart.

```
class UserCart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None) 

class Event(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(UserCart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'd like to develop a queryset of UserCart instances where there is a related event that is in the past (based on that event's start time)

```
pastcarts = UserCart.objects.filter(????)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as easy as:

```
pastcarts = UserCart.objects.filter(event__start_time__lt=<whatever_dt_you_prefer>)
```

You can read more in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) - check for reverse foreign key filtering.